# PyGtk3, How to Put Image to TreeViewColumn's title area?

Tags: pygtk

i want add an up/down arrow to TreeViewColumn's title area. but i can only add title. how can i add an arrow image with title to title area.

Thanks.

example:

```
col = gtk.TreeViewColumn(title = "name", cell)
col.add_image_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_GO_UP)

# or

col = gtk.TreeViewColumn(stock = gtk.STOCK_GO_UP, cell)
```

Answer (score 0):

`col.set_sort_column_id(column_num)` this method adds arrow and sorts items when column clicked.